# Has many Association with multple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There are  three models
User table attributes are name:string, age:integer, kind:integer.
Registration table attributes are user_id:integer, tutor_id:integer, event_id:integer, favorite:boolean.
Event table  attributes are name:string.
Here User kind can be of student, tutor or tutor_student

```
 # user.rb
    class User < ApplicationRecord
      enum kind: { student: 0, tutor: 1, tutor_student: 2 }
    
      has_many :registrations
      has_many :tutors, through: :registrations
      has_many :favorites, -> { where(registrations: { favorite: true }) }, through: :tutors, source: :event, class_name: 'Event'
    
    end
    
    # Event.rb
    class Event < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :registrations, foreign_key: :program_id
      has_many :users, through: :registrations
      has_many :tutors, through: :registrations
    end
    
    # registration.rb
    class Registration < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :tutor, class_name: 'User'
      belongs_to :event
    end
```

Here is the issue

I'm trying to get favorite tutors of user events through has many relations like above dummy data sample I has given

```
user.tutors.favorites
```

But I'm getting this error

```
undefined method `favorites' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007f04e8a7b540>
```

Can anyone help me to correct my association.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the error that you're getting, the reason you get `undefined method` is because you are technically calling `.favorites` on a collection of users not a single user.

You could get to the favorites of the users tutors by using something like:

```
user.tutors.joins(:registrations).where(registrations: {favorite: true})
```

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this user.tutors.favorites.ids by modifying association

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I've completely misunderstood what you're asking, but: `user.favorites`